# Is there any way to use mongodb database tools in google cloud app engine for nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, mongodump

I am trying to take backup of my MongoDb M0 cluster database using nodeJS. It is working in my local machine because mongodb database tool is installed in my local machine. But when i uploaded into google cloud app engine, getting error such **/bin/sh: 1: mongodump: not found**. I think this error is because of lack of mongodb database tools. So how can i fix this issue. Is there any other way to take mongo dump from cloud app engine ?

DEFAULT 2023-12-20T09:23:40.555945Z stderr:
DEFAULT 2023-12-20T09:23:40.555973Z /bin/sh: 1: mongodump: not found
DEFAULT 2023-12-20T09:23:40.556945Z Process exit with code: 127

these are the errors i am getting

Comment: May I know where you are running your `MongoDB` cluster? Is it running locally or you are using `MongoDB Atlas`? If you are using atlas have you check this [document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/manage-connections-google-cloud/#google-cloud-connection-example)? also have  a look at these links: [link1](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-from-google-app-engine/219934) & [link2](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-form-a-deployed-application-in-google-cloud/245798).

Comment: If these links doesn't help you, please provide minimal steps to recreate your issue

Comment: I am using mongodb atlas

Comment: I have installed the mongodb database tools in my local machine so i can take the dump from my local machine. I am using mongodb atlas with M0 cluster.So i want to backup the database. I can done this from my local machine, cron job and mongodump working fine. but i want this in my server, then only i can take the backup via cron job daily. my application in google cloud app engine

Comment: Have to tried to establish connection as stated in the [document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/manage-connections-google-cloud/#google-cloud-connection-example) i shared?